# How to search for a specific data from a JSON file with array in Cypress?

Tags: arrays, json, search, filter, cypress

I appreciate if someone help me in my question.
I need to validate a web page with 3 search fields. Also, I have a json file where I mocked it from the API.
So, I'm trying to type for a specific terminal and check if it works and it is not working. Instead of to show only the terminal number, the list is showing all the data.
I did the same validation with the API service and it worked as expected.

This is my code in Cypress

```js
  context('Search validation', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.intercept(
        'GET',
        '**/mc-extratos/**',
        {fixture: 'financeiro/carta-cancelamento'}
      ).as('verCartas')

      cy.visit('/carta-de-cancelamento')
      cy.get('[data-cy="consultarCartas"]')
        .as('Buscar') // nome do botão
        .click()
      cy.wait('@verCartas')
    })
    it('Search by Terminal',  () => {
      cy.get('#nroTerminal')
        .type('05009867')

      cy.get('@Buscar').click()
      cy.wait('@verCartas')
    })
```

And this is the part of my JSON file.
{"status":
{
"value":"0",
"description":"Requisição efetuada com sucesso."
},

```
"data": [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "ec": 11111111,
    "ecComercio": 900212,
    "ecName": "Estabelecimento 01",
    "cardMask": "515590XXXXXX0001",
    "nsu": "000150297",
    "authorization": "011064",
    "plan": "0212-parcelado lojista 12x",
    "transactionDate": "2022-03-18T00:00:00Z",
    "transactionValue": 212,
    "cancelDate": "2022-03-28T16:20:23Z",
    "cancelValue": 2,
    "cancelCode": "00-Transac?o aceita",
    "availableValue": 210,
    "terminal": "05009867",
    "product": "01-MASTERCARD",
    "microFilm": null,
    "channel": 990888,
    "channelName": "Web Manual",
    "user": "SISTEMA",
    "currency": 986,
    "currencyName": "Real",
    "filter": null
  },
  {
    "id": 264063,
    "ec": 22222222,
    "ecComercio": 831416,
    "ecName": "Estabelecimento 02",
    "cardMask": "515590XXXXXX0001",
    "nsu": "852736414",
    "authorization": "053768",
    "plan": "0203-parcelado lojista 3x",
    "transactionDate": "2022-03-03T00:00:00Z",
    "transactionValue": 303,
    "cancelDate": "2022-03-01T10:44:15Z",
    "cancelValue": 303,
    "cancelCode": "00-Transac?o aceita",
    "availableValue": 0,
    "terminal": "D5003826",
    "product": "01-MASTERCARD",
    "microFilm": "WS",
    "channel": 990113,
    "channelName": "WEB Service",
    "user": "HOST",
    "currency": 986,
    "currencyName": "Real",
    "filter": null
  }
]
```

}

[This is the web page where I have to write test in Cypress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wru5h.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [yielded response body from the `.wait()` command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait#Wait-for-a-specific-request-to-respond).

```js
cy.wait('@verCartas').then((res) => {
  // parse response body and destructure the data array.
  const { data } = JSON.parse(res.body)
  // iterate through data array
  data.forEach((element, index, array) => {
    // Any validations you need to run using the data
    // You'll probably want to identify the parent container element and select it using `.eq(index)`.
    cy.get('.some-parent-container').eq(index).within(() => {
      // code
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be that reusing `cy.get('[data-cy="consultarCartas"]')` via the alias `@Buscar` is the problem.

Try using `cy.get('[data-cy="consultarCartas"]')` directly after setting the filter

```js
it('Search by Terminal',  () => {
  cy.get('#nroTerminal')
    .type('05009867')

  cy.get('[data-cy="consultarCartas"]').click()
  cy.wait('@verCartas')

  cy.contains('tr', 'TERM')
    .should('have.length', 1)  // confirm filter worked
})
```